# Laravel 8 404 page not found, route exists

Tags: laravel-8

I refreshed my localhost webpage billion times but I got the same result, 404 page

CarsController.php

```
class CarsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CarsController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::resource('/cars', CarsController::class);
```

~\resources\views\cars\index.blade.php

```
CARS
```

I ran php artisan route:list and I got this

[image]

I tried php artisan route:cache but nothing changed

Comment: what URL are you trying to access? and is this a Laravel 404 page or a webserver 404 page?

Comment: I already solved it, it was my mistake when I put index page in another folder, thanks